# LaTex - BibTex: Comma at the End of Citation

Tags: latex, bibtex

When I cite something in my Latex-File the rendered citation alsways has a comma behind the last one (see the Picture)... 
How can I make this comma disappear?
[image: Wrong Citation with comma at the end]

The citations in the BibTex-File all look like this:

```
@inproceedings{chun10,
  title={Vizcept: Supporting synchronous collaboration for constructing visualizations in intelligence analysis},
  author={Chung, H. and Yang, S. and Ma{\ss}jouni, N. and Andrews, C. and Kanna, R. and North, C.},
  booktitle={Visual Analytics Science and Technology (VAST), 2010 IEEE Symposium on},
  pages={107--114},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

I call it as usual...

```
\cite{chun10}
```

And in my main document the important lines look like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{./Bib/frie13}
```

I included the germbib-package...

I don't have any idea for a solution.

Comment: A [MWE](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) based on your information results in a different output (but that may be because I didn’t use “germbib” as it isn’t installed with my system). – Also note that *you should **not** use germbib* as it’s obsolete.

Comment: Even when using `\usepackage{bibgerm}` I get a reference that looks like `[CYM+10]`.

Comment: I changed germbib to babelbib, but the result is the same...

Comment: @MichaelWild Could you post your file here? Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see it... If I use your file it could work...

Comment: @bethlis done. just as a side-note: you shouldn't quote numbers like years, days, volume, issue etc. in BibTeX. The formatting of them should be handled by the style file, and by quoting them you prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce what you see with below MWE:

test.tex:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

This sentence cites \cite{chun10}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```bib
@inproceedings{chun10,
  title={Vizcept: Supporting synchronous collaboration for constructing visualizations in intelligence analysis},
  author={Chung, H. and Yang, S. and Ma{\ss}jouni, N. and Andrews, C. and Kanna, R. and North, C.},
  booktitle={Visual Analytics Science and Technology (VAST), 2010 IEEE Symposium on},
  pages={107--114},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

The output is the following:

[image: Result of the MWE]